# How to check if Tomcat6 has stopped and need to start

Tags: debian, tomcat6

I am running tomcat6 on debian. How do I check the status of tomcat so to know if I should do `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start` or `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop`. Assume of course that I may or may not want to `start` if tomcat6 had been stopped, OR that I may or may not want to `stop` if tomcat had been started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the init.d-script of tomcat is somewhat standards conformant (and a quick check revealed that at least for squeeze this is true), then you can do:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 status
```